# Co-occurrence for set prediction

Tags: machine-learning

I'm having trouble with set prediction.  I thought I wanted to use co-occurrence to solve this, but now that I've attempted it I'm not sure it's the right tool to use.

I have a database with some data (each column corresponding to a specific item, each row corresponding to each set), e.g.:

```
data:
[[1 0 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1]
 [1 0 1 1]]
```

I calculate the co-occurrence matrix:

```
cooccur_matrix:
[[0 1 3 3]
 [1 0 1 1]
 [3 1 0 3]
 [3 1 3 0]]
```

And now I have an incomplete set:

```
target:
[1 0 1 1]
```

The dot product of my co-occurrence matrix and this is:

```
prediction:
[6 3 6 6]
```

But that's not at all what I want.  What I'm trying to get back is something like this:

```
prediction:
[1 0.33 1 1]
```

Or:

```
prediction:
[0 0.33 0 0]
```

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?  I'm fairly new to ML concepts, and this seems like a pretty simple problem.

Comment: apriori algorithm to start. normal recommender systems algorithm would work fine too.

Comment: @Mai I thought the method I'm using is what a normal recommendation system uses, is it not?

Comment: I don't think you would take dot product of concurrence, but the rows or columns of the raw matrix after mean-normalization. That's user-user or item-item CF. You can also try SVD++, and so on. I am not familiar with content-based methods, so the method you are referring to I may not know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like what I really needed was cosine similarity applied to a co-occurrence matrix.  This seems to work well (but was very hard to solve).